# Clear contents of range with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use a python script to clear data from specific ranges of an Excel spreadsheet. The script runs fine (I've tested printing worksheets to make sure the program is finding them), but the file is unchanged after I run the script and open the file.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = '10.28.17.xlsx')

ws = wb['Players']

for row in ws['A2:E49']:
  for cell in row:
    cell.value = 0
```

I would appreciate any assistance or tips you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save your workbook after your job:

```
wb.save("file_name.xlsx")
wb.close()
```